bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake) /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize':
I'm having problems when scheduling, it's a rake error
After creating the process and letting it run for 1 minute at a time, I logged in and ran
tail -f log/cron.log which returns the error message
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': 
Could not find rake-13.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

While I run that task alone without the "bundle exec rake batch:update_post" process, it works and in my GEM there is rake installed.
I am running on docker environment
and here is my schedule.rb file
set :output, "log/cron.log"

#Sets the environment to run during development mode (Set to production by default)
set :environment, "development

every 1.minute do
 # command "cd /app && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake batch:update_post --silent"
 rake "batch:update_post"
 puts "hello world"
end`

